# Como fazer o campo input file multiple em uma segunda seleção manter os arquivos selecionados anteriormente?

Tags: html, arquivo, input, multiple-file-upload, multiple

Ao Abrir a janela de seleção dos arquivos ele deixa eu selecionar múltiplos arquivos, OK!.

Porém após abrir os arquivos se o usuário clicar novamente para abrir mais arquivos ele limpa a seleção anterior...
Como fazer ele deixar a seleção anterior e somar a nova seleção ?

---

```html
<input type="file"  name="imagem[]" id="imagem[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Penso que você poderia utilizar um Event Listener como no exemplo que fiz abaixo. Assim, em cada novo input, você adiciona um File, ou mais, na Array `inputFiles`.

Ao clicar em *Remover* o File é eliminado da array.

Depois basta enviar para o back end a Array `inputFiles`.

```js
var inputFiles = [];

function newInput(input) {
  var filesStr = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
    inputFiles.push(input.files[i]);
    filesStr += "<li>" + input.files[i].name + "<button onclick='removeLi(this)'>Remover</button>" + "</li>";
  }

  document.getElementById("file-input").value = "";

  document.getElementById("dp-files").innerHTML += filesStr;
}

function removeLi(e) {
  inputFiles = inputFiles.filter(function(file) {
    return file.name !== e.parentNode.innerHTML.split("<button")[0];
  })
  e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<form id='form' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

  <input id='file-input' class='file-input' type='file' name='file' onchange="newInput(this)" multiple='multiple' />

</form>

<ul id="dp-files"></ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda.. porem preciso que ele mostre automático sem o botão "mostrar arquivos" e também um botão deletar individual por arquivo selecionado.

Comment: @RichardBarcelos - Conforme você solicitou editei a resposta original, acrescentando um sistema de delete e armazenamento dos arquivos em um array.

Comment: Beleza.

Mais surgiu outra dúvida rsrsr

Desculpe.

Como eu pegaria o array inputFiles ? se eu der um print_r no array ele ira me retornar?

Fiquei confuso nessa parte, geralmente dou um post[''];

se puder me dar essa dica agraço :)

Comment: Da uma olhadinha vê se essa outra pergunta te ajuda :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531155/send-array-of-files-using-ajax

Comment: Não estou usando json para pegar ou passar os dados, estou usando codeigniter

tentei pegar assim ja no meu controller

$files = $_FILES['inputFiles'];

porem sem sucesso

Comment: Eu tenho um form com esse input file e outros imputs que tbm preciso enviar para o meu action - eles etão enviando, porem na outra págian eu recebo eles e esse que montou não...

Comment: Te peço desculpas que não vou conseguir te ajudar além daqui, pois não trabalho com php :(( Até acho que seria interessante abrir uma outra questão específica sobre essa outra dúvida ou ver se alguém consegue te ajudar aqui nos comentários. De qualquer maneira te desejo sucesso na procura

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Eu ja dei uma pesquisada e parece que tenho que jogar as imagens deste array em um dos inputs que estou submetendo no form..

Estou descobrindo como fazer isso também.  Obrigado mais uma vez.