# Pegando arrays javascript para envio no formulário

Tags: php, javascript, array, array-multidimensional, array-push

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var nomess = [];

function handleFileSelect() {                                  

    var output = document.getElementById("resultt");
    arquivos = $("#imagem").prop("files");
    var nomes = $.map(arquivos, function(val) { return val.name; });

    //new
    var filesStr = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++) {
        var extensao = nomes[i].split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if(extensao == "doc" || extensao == "docx"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/word.png";
        }else if(extensao == "jpg" || extensao == "jpeg"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/jpg.png";
        }else if(extensao == "png"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/png.png";
        }else if(extensao == "xml"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/xml.png";
        }else if(extensao == "gif"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/gif.png";
        }else if(extensao == "pdf"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/pdf.png";
        }else if(extensao == "bmp"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/bmp.png";
        }else if(extensao == "txt"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/txt.png";
        }else if(extensao == "xlsx" || extensao == "xls"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/xls.png";
        }else{
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/file.png";
        }
        nomess.push(arquivos[i]);
        filesStr += "<li>" + arquivos[i].name + "<button onclick='removeLiy(this)' style='background-color:white; border:0'><i class='fas fa-trash' style='color:red; font-size: 24px; padding: 8px 0px 0px 3px;'></i></button><img src='"+icone+"' height='24' />" + "</li>";

    }

    console.log(nomess);

    document.getElementById("imagem").value = '';
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += filesStr;
    document.getElementById('imagem').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, true);

}

function removeLiy(e) {
    nomess = nomess.filter(function(imagem) {
        return imagem.name !== e.parentNode.innerHTML.split("<button")[0];
        //alert(nomess);
        console.log(nomess);
        //var aqui ='aqui';

    })
    e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
    console.log(nomess);
    //var aqui ='aqui nao';

    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(arquivos);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myJSON;

    console.debug('myJSON');

}

document.getElementById('imagem').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Estou tentando capturar os `Arrays` *Javascript* e passar para um `input hidden` do meu formulário para submeter ele e enviar a um arquivo *PHP* para upload.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo Richard Barcelos, você poderia adicionar o código que está utilizando?

Comment: olá amigo, sim. vou colocar.

Comment: Richard, vi que seu código faz muita coisa, você poderia detalhar melhor o seu problema para que eu possa entender?

Comment: Claro amigo, eu tenho um formulário com campos: de textarea, campo data e campo tipo file multiplos. Quando eu clico em adicionar files ele adiciona e cria um array com nomess.push.  Isto esta ok, adiciono e deleto, Meu problema é pegar o array gerado com as imagens e fazer enviar ao clicar no botão enviar do formulário.

Comment: quando dou um console.log(nomess) ele mostra a imagem que coloquei...

EU preciso pegar esse array nomes e colocar dentro do input file imagem para quando eu enviar o formulário ele enviar esses arquivos seleconados

Comment: neste outro post faço a mesma pergunta:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362273/como-fazer-o-campo-input-file-multiple-em-uma-segunda-sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o-manter-os-arquivos/362515#362515

Você saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: Você quer capturar um array de arquivos e adicionar ao valor de um *input hidden*, é isso?

Comment: Não sei se essa seria a melhor forma.. 
Pois não sei se o  input hidden conseguiria me passar  os dados para tratamento das imagens no arquivo php que o action do form envia... junto claro com os outros campos que ja tenho dentro do <form>

Comment: * Desculpe se estou explicando meio confuso rsrsr.
Preciso pegar este array de arquivos e enviar junto com meu formulário... para tratamento de upload

Comment: Conseguiu entender?

Comment: Vc que fazer isso porque o input file está fora do form?

Comment: Pq se tiver no form os arquivos já são enviados como array, não?

Comment: o input file esta dentro do form. EU seleciono por exemplo um file de uma pasta, depois de outra e assim vai ao final quero pegar todos que selecionei e armazenei no array javascript, ao clicar no enviar quero enviar todos os anexos.

Comment: Estão no forma mais não estão sendo enviados não..

Comment: @sam Você saberia como passar esse array das imagens para o envio do form??

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12006515/1377664). Acho que vc pega pelo name do input.

Comment: @Sam tentei aqui e não deu igual pegar pelo name do input

Answer (score 0):

Eu suspeito que você não consiga fazer o que está pretendendo porque nesse `array` `nomess` você não tem o caminho dos arquivos, mas apenas os nomes deles. Os browsers mais comuns não fornecem o endereço completo do arquivo para o JavaScript.

*Caso você tivesse o caminho completo de cada arquivo, minha sugestão seria adicionar uma function ao evento "submit" do form, que criaria um input `type="file"` dentro do form para cada arquivo do `array`.*

Uma alternativa seria carregar cada arquivo via JavaScript e passar isso no submit do `form` posteriormente. Há quem já tenha feito isso em algum momento da história, por exemplo, aqui: https://davidwalsh.name/fakepath#comment-49530
Mas acredito que isso seria outro tópico porque depois teria que dar um jeito de enviar esses arquivos para o PHP no fim das contas.

Enfim, eu respondi na sua outra pergunta (mesmo assunto) aqui:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363048/45707

Lá, eu expliquei como eu faria para clonar o input `type="file"` cada vez que ocorre o evento "change". Acredito que seja uma solução. Só fica o desafio de tratar o "remove" quando houver múltiplos files num mesmo input. Quem sabe se optar por retirar o atributo de multiple files e tratar de um em um?

Deixe-me saber se isso lhe ajudou ;)

Comment: Olá amigo, então agora me preocupou rsrsr
Pois o que quero fazer é pegar o arquivo selecionado no input file listar ele em uma lista onde pode ser retirado ou adicionado outros arquivos e ao clicar no form ele submeta o mesmo enviando os arquivos selecionados...

Comment: Javascript será que não seria a linguagem mais indicada? qual seria? para manter as informações do arquivo de caminho, peso, extensão.. para poder upar depois.. ? sera que me deu ruin? rsrsr

Comment: Quando falamos de manipulação no browser, `js` é o caminho mesmo. Acho que se você retirar o atributo "multiple" do input para tratar um arquivo por vez e usar o esquema que eu propus [aqui na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363048/45707) tem grande chance de solucionar sua questão.

Comment: Ok!  Porem eu preciso manter aquele formato de mostrar o ícone pelo if da extensão que montei e o deletar..

Comment: Entendi @RichardBarcelos acho que consigo elaborar mais a resposta lá pra você. Vamos seguir a conversa lá na outra pergunta? hehe acho que fica mais prático e organizado pra gente.

Comment: claro, eu sou meio novo na história, só preciso que seja como este codigo de incio.  Obrigado mais uma vez